# ALT Parsing error: Unexpected token (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React.js and have a problem with Alt. Something is missing in my code? Same with single and double quotation marks.

```
  26 |         <div>
  27 |              <h1>{item.name}</h1>
> 28 |              <img src={item.images.transparent} alt ""/>
     |                                                     ^
  29 |         </div>
  30 |     );
  31 | }
```

My code is: [CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQuHG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be

```
alt=""
```

not

```
alt ""
```

Comment: Oh god.. Thank you! Now there is a problem with a transparent. I have put images: {} to avoid it, but there is still an error.

Comment: what's inside : `item.images`, I think its array, you need to loop through it

Comment: Sorry I'm new here :D how I should loop through it? item.images should be fortnite items pictures. From the link

Comment: Will you please sned me the link, so I can check

Comment: https://fortnite-public-api.theapinetwork.com/prod09/item/get?ids=61ea3e9-8438e42-f53d351-e53a5ce
Here is a full link. But I'm cuting it from ids=....

Comment: I need to see the response of API, you can get the response an paste it over , https://codeshare.io/GAx0Je

Comment: Where I can find response from API? Is it this one? https://prnt.sc/t02jcs

Comment: Yes but you are getting error from that URL, first you need to solve that, then we can go ahead

Comment: Ok, I found the solution, thank you very much! Happy coding!

Comment: @RokasAšmena, great,glad to know